# Sharepoint. Custom buttons

Tags: sharepoint

I have a SharePoint site, I want all the buttons to be in center and visible, but some of them are out of borders, I replaced my file Default.aspx with another from site with buttons(I also copied Image folder and all files I need). But in my site all buttons are placed very left and I want them to be in center. 
What can I do? [image]

For example this is code of button with phone on it:

```
<tr>
                    <td width="181" height="120" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px">
                        <div class="mosaic-news right">
                            <div class="mosaic-overlay"> 
                                <a href="http://workpoint.company.corp/teams/TEM1/BAT%20IS/Pages/Telephony_rus.aspx" style="display: block">
                                <img class="teams" src="images/rus/telephony.png" alt=""/> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="details">
                                            <!-- INNER TEXT --> 
                                <div style="position: absolute; width: 182px; height: 120px">
                                    <p class="sq_section" style="top: 50%;height: 120px; margin-top: 40px;">Fabric phones<br/>and phones</p>
                                </div>
                                </a>
                                            <!-- END -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
```

Comment: Can we get access to your site?

Comment: Unfortunatelly no, it's locted on intranet of my company.

Comment: And could you provide the HTML of the buttons? Perhaps you can use <center> tag, but i depends on HTML and CSS you are using...